# Transition to expand transparent background from middle outward

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I want to make a CSS animation to open a transparent background from the center to the border (right and left) and leave the border red with text red and without any background.

Is it possible to do? I think I made a mistake with the class "bottone" but I don't know where!

The button needs to be like this, but with the colors inverted:

```css
.bottone {
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:hover {
  color: red;
}

.bottone:hover:after {
  width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<a class="bottone">example</a>
```

Here's another attempt:

```css
.bottone {
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.bottone:hover:after {
  width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<a class="bottone">example</a>
```

Comment: `.bottone:after { background: white }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "opening a transparent background", consider "moving two elements to *reveal* a transparent background". One idea is to use two pseudo-elements, `:before` and `:after`, that recede to opposite sides of the box.

In my example, one is `left:0` and the other is `right:0`.
Their widths both transition from 50% to 0.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.bottone {
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:hover {
  color: red;
}

.bottone:before,
.bottone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:before {
  left: 0;
}

.bottone:after {
  right: 0;
}

.bottone:hover:before,
.bottone:hover:after {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="bottone">example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Color need to be swapped.

pseudo size needs also to be set and reset on hover.

CSS commented

```css
.bottone {
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  color: white;/* inverted*/
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: color 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 110%;/* moved here */
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottone:hover {
  color: red;/* inverted */
}

.bottone:hover:after {
  width: 0;/* reset here */
}
```

```html
<a class="bottone">example</a>
```